# Carnot and Otto cycle diagrams in Latex using Tikz or PStricks

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks

How can I generate P-V or T-S plots for Carnot and Otto cycles? In addition to what are shown in the pictures, I would like to put directional arrows for steps starting from 1 to 4.

[image]

[image]

Also, I was trying to project the y-coordinates. But the annotations $P_1$ and $P_2$ are quite far from the axis.

```
  \documentclass{standalone}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.markings}

    \begin{document}

        \begin{tikzpicture}[
          > = latex,
          dot/.style = {draw,fill,circle,inner sep=1pt},
          arrow inside/.style = {postaction=decorate,decoration={markings,mark=at position .55 with \arrow{>}}}
          ]
          %\draw[<->] (0,6) node[above right] {$P$} |- (6,0) node[right] {$V$};
          %\draw[->] (0,0) node[above] {$P$} %|- (6,0) node[right] {$V$};
          \draw[->] (0,0) -- (6,0) node[right]{$V$};
          \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,6) node[left]{$P$};
          \node[dot,label={right:$a$}] (@a) at (5,4) {};
          \node[dot,label={left:$b$}] (@b) at (1.5,4.5) {};
          \node[dot,label={below left:$c$}] (@c) at (2,1.5) {};
          \node[dot,label={right:$d$}] (@d) at (5.5,1) {};
          \draw[arrow inside] (@a) to[looseness=.7,bend left=20] (@b);
          \draw[arrow inside] (@b) to[looseness=.7,bend right=20] (@c);
          \draw[arrow inside] (@c) to[looseness=.7,bend right=20] (@d);
          \draw[arrow inside] (@d) to[looseness=.7,bend left=20] (@a);
          \draw[dashed] (@a) to [left] (0,4);
          \draw[dashed] (@c) to [left] (0,1.5);
          \draw (-.98,4.0) node {$P_1$};
          \draw (-.98,1.5) node {$P_2$};
        \end{tikzpicture}


    \end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Is it because `tikzpicture` fails to comprehend negative coordinates?

Comment: Can you give the code of your first try?

Comment: Since these cycles have particular mathematical forms for the curve components (`\pi \tau \Sigma` members know this, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi_Tau_Sigma#/media/File:PiTauSigmakey.png), how essential is it that the figures match the actual functional forms?  Or are the figures merely schematic in nature?

Comment: @Steven No, the diagrams are schematics here since the working system doesn't need to be the "ideal gas"  or to follow a know equation of state.

Comment: @AndreC Hope you can see the code now.

Comment: Yes, but your code is not compileable !

Comment: On this site, it is customary to ask only one question at a time. This allows other users to find an answer to this one question. Here, you have 4 different graphs, which is a lot. A single question with a single problem, so a single graph is better. Can you change your question to that effect?

Comment: @AndreC Thanks for your recommendation. Any one of them would have worked for me. Just I need to get a generic template. I put the `documentclass` and other declarations now. Now you should be able to compile. Putting $Q_H$ and $Q_L$ still seems to be challenging for me.

Answer (score 1):

A Start....T-s diagram

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  > = latex,
  dot/.style = {draw,fill,circle,inner sep=1pt},
  arrow inside/.style = {postaction=decorate,decoration={markings,mark=at position .55 with \arrow{>}}}
  ]
  \draw[<->] (0,4.3) node[above right] {$T$} |- (4.3,0) node[right] {$s$};
  \node[dot,label={left:$1$}] (@1) at (1,3) {};
  \node[dot,label={right:$2$}] (@2) at (4,3) {};
  \node[dot,label={right:$3$}] (@3) at (4,1) {};
  \node[dot,label={left:$4$}] (@4) at (1,1) {};
  \draw[arrow inside] (@1) -- (@2);
  \draw[arrow inside] (@2) -- (@3);
  \draw[arrow inside] (@3) -- (@4);
  \draw[arrow inside] (@4) -- (@1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

EDIT

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  > = latex,
  dot/.style = {draw,fill,circle,inner sep=1pt},
  arrow inside/.style = {postaction=decorate,decoration={markings,mark=at position .55 with \arrow{>}}}
  ]
  \draw[<->] (0,4.3) node[above right] {$p$} |- (4.3,0) node[right] {$V$};
  \node[dot,label={left:$1$}] (@1) at (0.5,4) {};
  \node[dot,label={right:$2$}] (@2) at (2.5,3) {};
  \node[dot,label={right:$3$}] (@3) at (4,1) {};
  \node[dot,label={below left:$4$}] (@4) at (1.5,2) {};
  \draw[arrow inside] (@1) to[looseness=.7,bend right=20] (@2);
  \draw[arrow inside] (@2) to[looseness=.7,bend right=20] (@3);
  \draw[arrow inside] (@3) to[looseness=.7,bend left=20] (@4);
  \draw[arrow inside] (@4) to[looseness=.7,bend left=20] (@1);
  \draw[dashed,thin] (0,4) node[left] {$p_1$} -- (0.5,4);
  \draw[dashed,thin] (0.5,0) node[below] {$V_1$} -- (0.5,4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, what about including $Q_H$ and $Q_L$ with big arrows? Could that be difficult?

Comment: \draw[dashed,thin] (0,4) node[left] {$p_1$} -- (0.5,4); can be used for p_1

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

[image: screenshot]

Commented code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
    %\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.markings}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}% <-- new arrow library sinc version 3.0 of TikZ
    \usepackage[sfmath]{kpfonts}% <- use of sans serif kpfont family
    \begin{document}

        \begin{tikzpicture}[
          > = latex,
          directional arrow/.style={-{Stealth[inset=0pt, angle=45:8pt]},line width=2.5pt,red},%<-- new style for red arrows
          dot/.style = {draw,fill,circle,inner sep=1pt},
          arrow inside/.style = {postaction=decorate,decoration={markings,mark=at position .55 with \arrow{>}}}
          ]
          %\draw[<->] (0,6) node[above right] {$P$} |- (6,0) node[right] {$V$};
          %\draw[->] (0,0) node[above] {$P$} %|- (6,0) node[right] {$V$};
          \draw[->] (0,0) -- (6,0) node[right]{$V$};
          \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,6) node[left]{$P$};
          \node[dot,label={right:$a$}] (@a) at (5,4) {};
          \node[dot,label={left:$b$}] (@b) at (1.5,4.5) {};
          \node[dot,label={below left:$c$}] (@c) at (2,1.5) {};
          \node[dot,label={right:$d$}] (@d) at (5.5,1) {};
          \draw[arrow inside] (@a) to[looseness=.7,bend left=20] (@b);
          \draw[arrow inside] (@b) to[looseness=.7,bend right=20] (@c);
          \draw[arrow inside] (@c) to[looseness=.7,bend right=20] (@d);
          \draw[arrow inside] (@d) to[looseness=.7,bend left=20] (@a);
          \draw[dashed] (@a) to [left] (0,4);
          \draw[dashed] (@c) to [left] (0,1.5);
          \node[left] at (@a -| 0,0)  {$P_1$};% <- use of Coordinate system perpendicular (see page 141 of TikZ 3.1.1 manual
          \node[left] at (@c -| 0,0) {$P_2$};% <- idem
          \draw [directional arrow]($(@a)!.5!(@b)!0mm!-80:(@b)$)node[above,text=black]{$Q_H$}--($(@a)!.5!(@b)!7mm!80:(@b)$);%<- use of calc library
           \draw [directional arrow]($(@d)!.5!(@c)!0mm!-80:(@c)$)--($(@d)!.5!(@c)!7mm!80:(@c)$)node[below,text=black]{$Q_L$};
        \end{tikzpicture}


    \end{document}
```